# Ionic (Angular) rgba values not working in Android

Tags: android, css, angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

Using latest Angular with Ionic 7, Facing an issue in element style.

In component stlye file provided rbga property not working as expected in the android apk installed in mobile, working fine in web app

[image: Inspected Style]

Actual Scss

```
.accordian-style{
  margin: 1em;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

Comment: Which hex values are invalid?

Comment: here the rgba(0,0,0,.2) is converted to #0003 and rgba(0,0,0,.14) to #00000024 and rgba(0,0,0,.12) to #0000001f, which actual throws invalid property values

Comment: They look valid to me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 113.0.5672.64, which is up to date and my browserslistrc as below

Chrome >=79
ChromeAndroid >=79
Firefox >=70
Edge >=79
Safari >=14
iOS >=14

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems on Chrome Version 113.0.5672.64 (Official Build) (64-bit) on WIndows 10.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, It was working fine as web app in chrome browser, the screenshot attached is for the android app

Comment: Perhaps update your question with this clarification, and tag with android to attract those with that knowledge.

Comment: Hi @KesavanRamalingam, i having same issue. Did anyone find solution?